# my domain (abc.com) is wordpress site - how can my subdomain (xyz.abc.com) be setup to use a react.js app hosted on github page/azure/e.t.c

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, amazon-web-services, iis, dns

I want my reactjs project thats hosted somewhere online (either on ghpages,azure, or other solution). to be loaded when going to my wordpress sites subdomain.
there shouldnt be any links between the sub domain and the main domain. the reactjs project on the intended sub domain is just a webapp for administrative purposes that does CRUD operations on a cloud hosted api&db with a login to access the subdomain.

is this just a dns entry or how can i achieve linking a subdomain to a hosted reactjs project ?

Expecting users to go to my main domain thats a wordpress site with contact information and company informations,
and administrators to go on the subdomain thats running a reactjs project where you authenticate to gain access and there is forms to do CRUD operations to a cloud hosted API&DB

Comment: Yes you are correct about a DNS entry. You will want to ask the hosting company where the reactjs subdomain project will be located about their required settings. Some hosting companies use A records, some use CNAMEs, and some use alternatives. They will be able to guide you best